# equality operator overloading in swift enums with associated values

Tags: swift, enums, operator-overloading, equality

I know an almost similar question was asked earlier, but I am not able to comment on it, because I am to new here. That is the reason why I am posting a separat question. Also my question is an extension to the previous question asked and is aimed at a more general solution. That is the link to the previous question: [How to test equality of Swift enums with associated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339807/how-to-test-equality-of-swift-enums-with-associated-values)

I want to test equality in an enum with associated values:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case None
    case Error
    case Function(Int) // it is a custom type but for briefness an Int here
    case ...
}
```

I tried to setup an overloading function as the following

```
func ==(a: MyEnum, b: MyEnum) -> Bool {
    switch (a,b) {
    case (.Function(let aa), .Function(let bb)):
        if (aa==bb) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    default:
        if (a == b) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

This gives no compile time error, but fails with bad_exec in the running process. Most likely because testing a==b in the default case, calls the function itself again. The .Function part works as expected, but not the rest... So the case list is somewhat longer, how can I test the cases which do not have an associated value with them for equality?

Comment: I just added an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41034836/2784160

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your implementation,

```
if (a == b) {
```

*recursively* calls the same `==` function again. This eventually crashes with a stack overflow.

A working implementation would for example be:

```
func ==(a: MyEnum, b: MyEnum) -> Bool {
    switch (a,b) {
    case (.Function(let aa), .Function(let bb)):
        return aa == bb
    case (.Error, .Error):
        return true
    case (.None, .None):
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, you already had noticed the recursion (sorry for reading the question not carefully enough). Let's see if a better solution comes up ...

Comment: Still thanks for posting this! Because for a short enum list this is probably the best and simple solution. And it is straight forward. But if you have a long list of cases, I am still wondering if there is a more elegant (and shorter) solution. Because it would be a lot of writing for a very simple question... lhs is equal to rhs

Answer (score 0):

Although `memcmp` works:

```
func ==(var a: MyEnum, var b: MyEnum) -> Bool {
    switch (a,b) {
    case (.Function(let aa), .Function(let bb)):
        return aa == bb
    default:
        return memcmp(&a, &b, sizeof(MyEnum)) == 0
    }
}
```

I don't recommend this :)