# How to compare enum with associated values by ignoring its associated value in Swift?

Tags: swift, enums, comparison

After reading [How to test equality of Swift enums with associated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339807/how-to-test-equality-of-swift-enums-with-associated-values), I implemented the following enum:

```
enum CardRank {
    case Number(Int)
    case Jack
    case Queen
    case King
    case Ace
}

func ==(a: CardRank, b: CardRank) -> Bool {
    switch (a, b) {
    case (.Number(let a), .Number(let b))   where a == b: return true
    case (.Jack, .Jack): return true
    case (.Queen, .Queen): return true
    case (.King, .King): return true
    case (.Ace, .Ace): return true
    default: return false
    }
}
```

The following code works:

```
let card: CardRank = CardRank.Jack
if card == CardRank.Jack {
    print("You played a jack!")
} else if card == CardRank.Number(2) {
    print("A two cannot be played at this time.")
}
```

However, this doesn't compile:

```
let number = CardRank.Number(5)
if number == CardRank.Number {
    print("You must play a face card!")
}
```

... and it gives the following error message:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CardRank' and '(Int) -> CardRank'

I'm assuming this is because it's expecting a full type and `CardRank.Number` does not specify an entire type, whereas `CardRank.Number(2)` did. However, in this case, I want it to match **any** number; not just a specific one.

Obviously I can use a switch statement, but the whole point of implementing the `==` operator was to avoid this verbose solution:

```
switch number {
case .Number:
    print("You must play a face card!")
default:
    break
}
```

Is there any way to compare an enum with associated values while ignoring its associated value?

**Note:** I realize that I could change the case in the `==` method to `case (.Number, .Number): return true`, but, although it would return true correctly, my comparison would still look like its being compared to a specific number (`number == CardRank.Number(2)`; where 2 is a dummy value) rather than *any* number (`number == CardRank.Number`).

Comment: You can reduce the `Jack`, `Queen`, `King`, `Ace` cases in the `==` operator implementation to just: `case (let x, let y) where x == y: return true`

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-enum-property-without-initializing-the-enum-case-with-an-associated-value/17539 and https://forums.swift.org/t/request-ability-to-refer-to-an-enum-case-in-abstract-without-its-associated-value/410

Answer (score 116, accepted):

**Edit:** As Etan points out, you can omit the `(_)` wildcard match to use this more cleanly:

```swift
let number = CardRank.Number(5)
if case .Number = number {
    // Is a number
} else {
    // Something else
}
```

---

Unfortunately, I don't believe that there's an easier way than your `switch` approach in Swift 1.2.

In Swift 2, however, you can use the new `if-case` pattern match:

```swift
let number = CardRank.Number(5)
if case .Number(_) = number {
    // Is a number
} else {
    // Something else
}
```

If you're looking to avoid verbosity, you might consider adding an `isNumber` computed property to your enum that implements your switch statement.

Comment: This is great for control flow, but it kinda sucks when you just want a simple expression, eg: `assert(number == .Number)`. I can only hope this is improved in later versions of Swift. =/

Comment: Also sucks for things like while loop conditions etc. In Swift 3 you can remove the (_) for a cleaner code.

Comment: Thanks @Etan, I've added that to the answer. You can actually omit the wildcard in Swift 2 too. This answer was written before the language feature was released, so I didn't know that yet! :-D

Comment: Also: If an enum has a single case with associated values, the if-case pattern needs to be used even for those cases that do not have associated values.

Comment: Can you negate the if case? Doesn't seem possible to do `if case .Number != number`

Comment: @PeterWarbo, you cannot do negation with this pattern-matching syntax. You'll have to fall back to a `default` case in a `switch` block for now.

Comment: How to use this in conditional modifiers? Like ‘number == .Number ? X : X’ ?

Answer (score 39):

Unfortunately in Swift 1.x there isn't another way so you have to use `switch` which isn't as elegant as Swift 2's version where you can use `if case`:

```
if case .Number = number {
    //ignore the value
}
if case .Number(let x) = number {
    //without ignoring
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this only works in `if` statements, not as an expression.

Comment: @Raphael in Swift 5.9 we get if and switch expressions so I think this might work as an expression.

Answer (score 28):

In Swift 4.2 `Equatable` will be synthesized if all your associated values conform to `Equatable`. All you need to do is add `Equatable`.

```
enum CardRank: Equatable {
    case Number(Int)
    case Jack
    case Queen
    case King
    case Ace
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable?changes=_3

Comment: Though this will compare associated values.

Answer (score 18):

What I usually do to compare if two enum cases "match" no matter their associated value is:

I have a protocol `Matchable`:

```swift
protocol Matchable {
  static func ~= (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
}
```

Then I make enums conform to it:

```swift
extension CardRank: Matchable {
  static func ~= (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
      case
        (.number, .number),
        (.jack, .jack),
        (.queen, .queen),
        (.king, .king),
        (.ace, .ace):
        return true
        
      default:
        return false
    }
  }
}

let card1: CardRank = .number(1)
let card2: CardRank = .number(2)
let card3: CardRank = .jack

print(card1 ~= card2) // true
print(card1 ~= card3) // false
```

Comment: I think this is a great answer, because it shows its doesn't behave the same as people might expect == to... You also should make a !~= and make it return the opposite.

Comment: I like this, although I wouldn't use a custom operator.  Instead I would create a member function called `matchesCaseType` so the above would read `card1.matchesCaseType(card2)` which IMO is much clearer at the call site, a tenet of the Swift API Design Guidelines (https://www.swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines). Plus, it allows for easy negation as well... `if !card1.matchesCaseType(card2) { ... }`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simpler approach:

```
enum CardRank {
    case Two
    case Three
    case Four
    case Five
    case Six
    case Seven
    case Eight
    case Nine
    case Ten
    case Jack
    case Queen
    case King
    case Ace

    var isFaceCard: Bool {
        return (self == Jack) || (self == Queen) || (self == King)
    }
}
```

There's no need to overload the == operator, and checking for card type does not require confusing syntax:

```
let card = CardRank.Jack

if card == CardRank.Jack {
    print("You played a jack")
} else if !card.isFaceCard {
    print("You must play a face card!")
}
```

Comment: Though it doesn't answer the overarching question, IMO this is a more elegant solution (enumerated Numbers aside) in scenarios similar to OP's and shouldn't be downvoted.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't want to conform `Equatable` (it didn't help me either) and I wanted to filter for other cases than a specific one, so instead of simply writing `card != .Number` I had to write the following. (I adjusted my code to this question.)

```
enum CardRank {
    ...
    var isNumber: Bool {
       if case .Number = self { return true }
       return false
    }
}
```

So I can write *not a number* in a complex condition:

```
if something && !card.isNumber { ... }
```

I wish I could just write `card != .Number`, but the compiler was always complaining with **Type of expression is ambiguous without more context.** Maybe in an upcoming swift version!

Answer (score 3):

```
extension CardRank {
    func isSameCaseAs(_ other: CardRank) -> Bool {
        switch (self, other) {
        case (.Number, .Number),
            (.Jack, .Jack),
            (.Queen, .Queen),
            (.King, .King),
            (.Ace, .Ace):
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}

let number = CardRank.Number(1)
let otherNumber = CardRank.Number(2)
number.isSameCaseAs(otherNumber) // true
```

Just create an extension and ignore the associated types.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `func ==` or `Equatable`. Just use an [enumeration case pattern](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#ID424).

```swift
let rank = CardRank.Ace
if case .Ace = rank { print("Snoopy") }
```

Answer (score -1):

From Swift 5.3, you can use the [Comparable Enums](https://betterprogramming.pub/comparable-enum-in-swift-374836f02251) feature:

```
enum CardRank: Comparable {
    case Number(Int)
    case Jack
    case Queen
    case King
    case Ace
}

let cards: [CardRank] = [
    .Queen, .Number(8), .Ace, .Number(3), .King
]

print(cards.sorted())
// [.Number(3), .Number(8), .Queen, .King, .Ace]
```

Comment: Wouldn't this compare the associated values as well, which the question has asked to ignore?

Answer (score -2):

```
let cardRank = CardRank.Number(10)    
guard let case .Number(someNumber) = cardRank else {
      return
}
print(someNum)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment, it is recommended to also explain the code instead of only including the code for the answer to be more useful for future readers. Not just provide the code for solving the issue but also explain why and how it solves it. Also, I want to note that people can pretty much bote however they want. People cannot really be held accountable for their votes. See also [Should 'drive by' downvoting be more effectively caught?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397)