# How to check enum case of enum with associated values in Swift

Tags: swift, enums

I'm trying to check the case of an enum that has associated values for each case like this:

```
enum status {
    case awake(obj1)
    case sleeping(obj2)
    case walking(obj3)
    case running(obj4)
}
```

I'm using `if(status == deviceStatus.awake){` to check status case and am getting an error: `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'status' and '(obj1) -> status'`

Comment: Where have you defined your deviceStatus? and what type of those objects (obj1, obj2, ...) are?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/31548855/994104

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `if case .awake = deviceStatus` to check if `deviceStatus` is set to the `awake` enumeration value:

```
class Obj1 { }
class Obj2 { }
class Obj3 { }
class Obj4 { }

enum Status {
    case awake(Obj1)
    case sleeping(Obj2)
    case walking(Obj3)
    case running(Obj4)
}

let deviceStatus = Status.awake(Obj1())

if case .awake = deviceStatus {
    print("awake")
} else if case .sleeping = deviceStatus {
    print("sleeping")
}

// you can also use a switch statement

switch deviceStatus {
case .awake:
    print("awake")
case .sleeping:
    print("sleeping")
default:
    print("something else")
}
```