# Can I test whether an enum value is a particular case without using a switch statement?

Tags: swift, enums

Consider:

```
enum Test {
    case foo
    case bar
    case baz
    case etc
}

var test: Test = ...
```

I would like to test whether the enum is `bar` in particular. I could just use a switch statement:

```
switch test {
case .bar:
    doSomething()
default:
    break
}
```

It would be far neater if I could instead use `if`:

```
if test == .bar {
    doSomething()
}
```

But unless I'm missing something, there is no way to do that:

`Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'Test' operands`

Is this possible, and if not, was this a deliberate language design decision?

Comment: Your code compiles fine as `Test` doesn't have any associated values (Swift only synthesises `Hashable` conformance for enums without associated values). Please show us your real code.

Comment: Assuming `Test` in your real code does in fact have associated values – possible duplicate of [How to compare enum with associated values by ignoring its associated value in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31548855/2976878). Also see [How to test equality of Swift enums with associated values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24339807/2976878)

Comment: @Hamish: Sorry, yes, I can confirm that my real code has associated values for some cases. However, I'm trying to compare against one that doesn't. Assume that `baz` and `etc` have associated values, but `foo` and `bar` do not.

Comment: In that case – possible duplicate of [How to test equality of Swift enums with associated values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24339807/2976878) :)

Answer (score 66):

You can use the `if-case` operand

```
if case .foo  = test {
   doSomething()
}
```