# How can I compare two enum instances with NO raw type?

Tags: swift, enums

Given:

```
enum Example { case Step1 case Step2(data: String)  }
```

and:

```
let a: Example = .Step1
let b: Example = .Step2(data: "hi")
```

how do I make this work?

```
print(a == b) // ERROR: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'Example' operands
```

Note that I can't give up the custom enum (it cannot contain raw values)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548855/how-to-compare-enum-with-associated-values-by-ignoring-its-associated-value-in-s might also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the [`Equatable`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/equatable) protocol for your enum.

```
enum Example: Equatable {
    case Step1
    case Step2(data: String)

    static func == (lhs: Example, rhs: Example) -> Bool {
        switch(lhs) {
        case Step1:
            switch(rhs) {
            case Step1:
                return true
            default:
                return false
            }
        case Step2(data: leftString):
            switch(rhs) {
            case Step2(data: rightString):
                return leftString == rightString
            default:
                return false
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Is this the only solution? It seems very ugly if you have more of 2 cases!

Comment: You can just use `default`, so it scales with the number of cases instead of the square of the number of cases.

Comment: Yep, I got it. It's a little lack in swift IMHO