# Using `if-case` format in boolean assignment in Swift?

Tags: swift, enums

If I have the following enum defined:

```
enum CardRank {
  case number(Int)
  case jack
  case queen
  case king
  case ace
}
```

I know [I can use an `if-let` to check if it's a number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31549464/35690):

```
let cardRank = CardRank.number(5)
if case .number = cardRank {
  // is a number
} else {
  // something else
}
```

Instead of using an if statement, though, I want to assign the boolean result of "is this a number" to a variable.

E.g. something like this:

```
let isNumber = (case .number = cardRank)
```

However, this gives me the compiler error:

```
error: expected expression in list of expressions
let isNumber = (case .number = cardRank)
                ^
```

**Is there a similar 1-line syntax to get this kind of assignment to work?**

The closest I got was this, but it's pretty messy:

```
let isNumber: Bool = { if case .number = cardRank { return true } else { return false } }()
```

---

I know I can [implement the Equatable protocol on my enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339807/how-to-test-equality-of-swift-enums-with-associated-values), and then do the following:

```
let isAce = cardRank == .ace
```

But I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require needing to conform to the Equatable protocol.

Answer (score 5):

Add it as a property on the enum:

```
extension CardRank { 
    var isNumber: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .number: return true
        default: return false
        }
    }
}

let isNumber = cardRank.isNumber
```