# iOS RxSwift how to check if Result == .success?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I'm only interested in results with `.success` type that come from my query.

**How can I set a filter to only pass through .success results from `Result<Value>` enum?**

```
public enum Result<Value> {
    case success(Value)
    case failure(Error)
}


query.filter{ (result: Result<Double>) in
                switch result {
                case .success:
                    return true
                case .failure:
                    return false
                }
            }
```

I want to do shorthand check for success only, but compiler does not allow this.

```
.filter{result in
    return result == .success
}
```

Comment: This is an unfortunate current shortcoming when working with enums with associated values – a common solution is to add a computed property to the enum to test for a given case. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/46005134/2976878. There have been a couple of fairly recent pitches looking to improve the situation: https://forums.swift.org/t/automatically-derive-properties-for-enum-cases/10843 and https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-auto-synthesize-cases-for-enums/10075

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a one-liner, not as short as you described, but shorter than the switch:

```
if case .success = result { return true } else { return false }
```

Enums with associated values need pattern matching, thus you need an `if`/`switch`/`for`/`while` to make that happen.

Alternatively, if you use this kind of filtering in multiple places, you could extend `Result`:

```
extension Result {
    var isSuccess: Bool { if case .success = self { return true } else { return false } }

    var isError: Bool {  return !isSuccess  }
}
```

, and use this extension:

```
query.filter { $0.isSuccess }
```

Or a functional approach, where `isSuccess` an `isError` are global functions:

```
func isSuccess<T>(_ result: Result<T>) -> Bool {
    if case .success = result { return true } else { return false }
}

func isError<T>(_ result: Result<T>) -> Bool {
    return !isSuccess(result)
}

// later in the code
query.filter(isSuccess)
```

The latter approach comes with a small performance benefit, as the compiler doesn't need to create another closure every time, and will use the one stored under the `isSuccess` name. Though it doesn't fully complies with the Swift conventions that recommend adding member functions instead of free ones.

Comment: I'm getting this error when trying this line: [ Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer ]

Comment: @AlexStone had a typo, should've been only one `=`, corrected the answer, and added another alternative.

Comment: Now the Great Swift Compiler is happy :)

Comment: Your extension should be `... if case .success = self ...`

Comment: Thanks, @José, I updated the answer with your feedback a while ago, but missed to acknowledge it.