# Swift check if an error variable is NOT a specific case of some error

Tags: swift, error-handling, enums

I have an error and I need to check if it's **NOT** a specific case of MyError:

```
enum MyError {
    case one(description: String)
    case two(description: String)
    case three(description: String)
    (...)
}
```

I can easily check if an `error` variable is a specific case of MyError:

```
if case MyError.one = error {
    // this is definitely error MyError.one
}
```

How can I make sure it's NOT a specific case?

```
if (...) { // something like: !(case MyError.one = error)
    // this is any other case but NOT MyError.one
}
```

I know I can do this with the `guard` keyword or `if-else` but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution (as guard needs a `return`):

```
guard case MyError.one = error else {
    // this is any other case but NOT MyError.one
    return
}
```

Comment: `switch error {
case .one:
    break
default:
    print("not one")
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also add helper methods to your enum:

```
enum MyError {
    case one(description: String)
    case two(description: String)
    case three(description: String)

    var isOne:Bool {
        if case MyError.one = self {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, doing anything simpler than this is not currently possible. Here are a couple of good threads on this and related subjects:

1. [How to compare enum with associated values by ignoring its associated value in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548855/how-to-compare-enum-with-associated-values-by-ignoring-its-associated-value-in-s)
2. [How to test equality of Swift enums with associated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339807/how-to-test-equality-of-swift-enums-with-associated-values)

Comment: Yes, I could do do the same with an `if-else` statement. I'm just trying to find a way to do it like `if !(case MyError.one = error) { ...`

Comment: Thanks, it does not exactly solve my problem but I see it can't be done as I hoped. The solution with a computed property should be sufficient (although it's not ideal).