# How do you check elegantly case enum in the .first(where:) closure in Swift?

Tags: swift, enums

Let's say I have this enum:

```
enum Item {
  case foo(String)
  case bar(String)
}
```

and a list of it:

```
let items: [Item] = [.foo("aa"), .bar("bb")]
```

I'd like to find the **first** `foo` item of it, this is what I did:

```
items.first { (item) -> Bool in
  switch item {
  case .foo:
    return true
  default:
    return false
  }
}
```

Is there any elegant way to write something like:

```
items.first { case .foo = $0 }
```

(Above code not working, apparently)

Comment: Do you need a foo/bar with an specific string value or just any foo case? Do you need to return the string value associated with it?

Comment: Hi Leo, I just need any foo case, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare enum with associated values by ignoring its associated value in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548855/how-to-compare-enum-with-associated-values-by-ignoring-its-associated-value-in-s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`first` won't do anything useful. I think you want `contains`.

```swift
items.contains { Item.foo ~= $0 }
```

Regardless, you'll need this:

```swift
/// Match `enum` cases with associated values, while disregarding the values themselves.
/// - Parameter case: Looks like `Enum.case`.
public func ~= <Enum: Equatable, AssociatedValue>(
  case: (AssociatedValue) -> Enum,
  instance: Enum
) -> Bool {
  Mirror.associatedValue(of: instance, ifCase: `case`) != nil
}

/// Match `enum` cases with associated values, while disregarding the values themselves.
/// - Parameter case: Looks like `Enum.case`.
public func ~= <Enum, AssociatedValue>(
  case: (AssociatedValue) -> Enum,
  instance: Enum
) -> Bool {
  Mirror.associatedValue(of: instance, ifCase: `case`) != nil
}

/// Match non-`Equatable` `enum` cases without associated values.
public func ~= <Enum>(pattern: Enum, instance: Enum) -> Bool {
  guard (
    [pattern, instance].allSatisfy {
      let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: $0)
      return
        mirror.displayStyle == .enum
        && mirror.children.isEmpty
    }
  ) else { return false }

  return .equate(pattern, to: instance) { "\($0)" }
}
```

```swift
public extension Mirror {
  /// Get an `enum` case's `associatedValue`.
  static func associatedValue<AssociatedValue>(
    of subject: Any,
    _: AssociatedValue.Type = AssociatedValue.self
  ) -> AssociatedValue? {
    guard let childValue = Self(reflecting: subject).children.first?.value
    else { return nil }

    if let associatedValue = childValue as? AssociatedValue {
      return associatedValue
    }

    let labeledAssociatedValue = Self(reflecting: childValue).children.first
    return labeledAssociatedValue?.value as? AssociatedValue
  }

  /// Get an `enum` case's `associatedValue`.
  /// - Parameter case: Looks like `Enum.case`.
  static func associatedValue<Enum: Equatable, AssociatedValue>(
    of instance: Enum,
    ifCase case: (AssociatedValue) throws -> Enum
  ) rethrows -> AssociatedValue? {
    try associatedValue(of: instance)
      .filter { try `case`($0) == instance }
  }

  /// Get an `enum` case's `associatedValue`.
  /// - Parameter case: Looks like `Enum.case`.
  static func associatedValue<Enum, AssociatedValue>(
    of instance: Enum,
    ifCase case: (AssociatedValue) throws -> Enum
  ) rethrows -> AssociatedValue? {
    try associatedValue(of: instance).filter {
      .equate(try `case`($0), to: instance) {
        Self(reflecting: $0).children.first?.label
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension Optional {
  /// Transform `.some` into `.none`, if a condition fails.
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - isSome: The condition that will result in `nil`, when evaluated to `false`.
  func filter(_ isSome: (Wrapped) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Self {
    try flatMap { try isSome($0) ? $0 : nil }
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension Equatable {
  /// Equate two values using a closure.
   static func equate<Wrapped, Equatable: Swift.Equatable>(
    _ optional0: Wrapped?, to optional1: Wrapped?,
    using transform: (Wrapped) throws -> Equatable
  ) rethrows -> Bool {
    try optional0.map(transform) == optional1.map(transform)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I've updated the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 5):

#### Enumerators *with* associated values (edited question)

If you have an enum whose enumerators have associated values, you could replace the `switch` statement if the `if case (let) ... else` statement, as you are exclusively searching for a given enumerator pattern (and none of the rest -> `else`). E.g.:

```
let item = items.first { 
    if case .foo = $0 { return true }
    else { return false }
}
```

#### Enumerators without associated values (original question)

`=` is assignment, whereas `==` is equality comparison. Here, you want the latter:

```
let item = items.first { $0 == .foo }

// or
let item = items.first { .foo == $0 }
```

You can also use pattern matching using the `~=` operator:

```
let item = items.first { $0 ~= .foo }

// or
let item = items.first { .foo ~= $0 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I've updated the question to make it more clear as it's an enum without an associated value.

Comment: @dfrib OP solution should work as well. It is not clear what OP is trying to accomplish. Maybe OP wants to return the string value.

Comment: @LeoDabus True; I always favoured `if case let ... else` over `switch - case - default` for searching for a single enumerator, but I agree OP probably did not state exactly what was the actual intention. My first Swift answer in years! I'm surprised we aren't allowed to use pattern matching directly (`... first { .foo ~= $0 }`); was that never a thing for enumerators with associated values? I guess we'd need to implement our custom `~=` overload for the `Item` type?

Comment: Welcome back buddy. I've never played with a collection of associated values

Comment: `if let item = items.first(where: {` `switch $0 {` `case .foo: return true` `default: return false }}), case let .foo(string) = item {` `print(string)` `}`. Arghhh Thats why I don't like enumerations with associated values.

Comment: You can use a generalized solution, like I have in my answer. There's been talk on the Swift forum of improving it without relying on reflection and extensions.