# Swift Enum Equatable expected argument issue

Tags: swift, enums, equatable

I am using an enum as follows:

```
enum Views: Equatable {
    case home
    case poules(pouleID: String?)
}
```

I have to set an enum variable to `.home` or `.poules`. Poules can also have an argument like: `router.currentView = .poules(pouleID: "TEST")`.

However, when I want to test if the variable is of type `.home` or `.poules` (and no not want to extract the parameter), I get the following error:

```
if router.currentView == .poules { // <--- (Error: Member 'poules(pouleID:)' expects argument of type 'String')
    // Do something
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have used the same structure for other Enums and have not experienced any problems there.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/31548855/1187415

Comment: @MartinR seen that question, does not solve the issue

Comment: Yet, the `if case` is the solution to know if the `Views` value is a .poule(someIdYouDonTUse)

Comment: @Björn: Are you sure? `if case .poules = router.currentView {}` as in  (e.g.) https://stackoverflow.com/a/31549476/1187415 should do the trick.

Comment: Ah I see, works for the if statements indeed. Thanks!! Do you know how to handle inline conditional modifiers such as `.transition(viewRouter.originView == .poules ? X : X)` ?

Comment: That is not possible, as far as I know.

Comment: You can use `if router.currentView == .poules(let _)`.

Comment: @HunterLion unfortunately, that does not work

Comment: @MartinR is there an alternative to work with equatable enums in modifiers? Seem strange to me that such a simple thing is not possible?

Comment: If you have only this 2 case  in enum, test ´ != .home ´

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple way to test if a variable is of type `.poules` is to move the actual comparison inside a computed property of the enum. This also makes sense since this comparison isn't really what you would use for `Equatable`

```
var isAnyPoules: Bool {
    if case .poules = self { return true }

    return false
}
```

This will make it easier to perform the check

```
if router.currentView.isAnyPoules
```

or

```
.transition(viewRouter.originView.isAnyPoules ? X : X)
```