# Swift enums with arguments: how to compare them?

Tags: swift, enums, equatable

I have the following enum:

```
enum Message: ErrorType {
    case MessageWithInfo(info:String?)
    case MessageDidFail
    case MessageDidSend(info:String)
    case InvalidMessageData
    case MessageWithDelay(delay:Double)
    .... will keep adding more
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to write the Equatable function that would let me then compare Message enums.

I found some similar questions on stack overflow, but I couldn't find one that would allow me to compare without having to switch on every single case.

Is there a way to write the equatable function once and have it work even if I keep adding more cases to this enum?

Comment: For enums with associated values you have to implement the == yourself explicitly. That means that you have to switch on every possible case. I don't think there is a way around it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test equality of Swift enums with associated values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339807/how-to-test-equality-of-swift-enums-with-associated-values).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible write one function that will work for all enums with all kinds of cases. Which basically is what you want.

The reason is discusses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007461/how-to-enumerate-an-enum-with-string-type). The second answer shows a method that can be used with enums that have a rawValue.

This is because an Enum of mixed types loses it's rawValue.

You can write a switch to get a rawValue (you have to ignore the associated values). But this can't be done automatically.

With a Struct or Class you also can not write a method that automatically creates a sequence/set of all the var's let's declared in it. Just like an Enum is not able to make a sequence/set out of it's cases.

```
enum Message: ErrorType {

    case MessageWithInfo(info:String?)
    case MessageDidFail
    case MessageDidSend(info:String)
    case InvalidMessageData
    case MessageWithDelay(delay:Double)

    var rawValue : Int {
        get {
            switch self {
            case .MessageWithInfo(info: _) : return 0
            case .MessageDidFail : return 1
            case .MessageDidSend(info: _) : return 2
            case .InvalidMessageData : return 3
            case .MessageWithDelay(delay: _) : return 4

            }
        }
    }
}

func ==(lhs:Message,rhs:Message) -> Bool {

    return (lhs.rawValue == rhs.rawValue)

}
```