# In Swift, why can't a 'case' conditional match an enum case with no associated data...?

Tags: swift, enums, conditional-statements, case

Preamble: I understand that a practical work-around to my question is to use a full `switch` statement. I'm mainly asking to see if I'm misunderstanding Swift here.

Given an `enum`, for example:

```
enum Quark1 {
  case charm
  case strange
  // ...
}
```

A `guard` statement like below, which is how I'd like the code I'm writing to read, works fine:

```
guard someQuark != .charm else { // ... }
```

**However**, if one (or more, but *not all*) cases of my enum have associated data, like this:

```
enum Quark2 {
  case charm
  case strange(charge)
  // ...
}
```

Then the same 'guard case' statement...

```
guard someQuark != .charm else { // no bueno
```

...gets this error message:

```
Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Quark' and '_'
```

Is there a way to test for an enum case—*without* associated data, *from an enum where other cases do have associated data*—in a one line conditional, like `if` and `guard`?

Yes, a `switch` statement will get the job done. This is more a theory question than a practical problem.

p.s. Apologies to physicists, I realize these examples are not standard (hah!) models of real quarks.

(edited to highlight the crucial points)

Comment: Closely related: [How to test equality of Swift enums with associated values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339807/how-to-test-equality-of-swift-enums-with-associated-values)

Comment: @Hamish, thanks for finding an apropos question-and-answer! Apologies to all for missing it.

Comment: What's the stackoverflow protocol here?... @Hamish pointed out a previous answered question that directly addresses my question—should I answer my own question to point that fact out, leave it for someone else to make that an answer, or do nothing?

Comment: Well Martin's answer is also a good solution to the problem. Given that the other Q&A is more specific about requiring the comparison to be a boolean expression, whereas your question is just about how to make the comparison with a guard, which Martin's answer covers, I would suggest leaving it as-is.

Comment: Note that `case strange(charge)` doesn't compile – you need to give `charge` a type.

Comment: Yes, that was a bit of 'lorem ipsum' there. Just thinking of how quarks have a charge property.