# How may I test the equivalency of enumeration cases with associated values in Swift 4

Tags: swift, enums, operators, equality, swift4

I would like to test the equivalency of a couple variables of enumeration types, like this:

```swift4
enum AnEnumeration {
  case aSimpleCase
  case anotherSimpleCase
  case aMoreComplexCase(String)
}

let a1 = AnEnumeration.aSimpleCase
let b1 = AnEnumeration.aSimpleCase
a1 == b1 // Should be true.

let a2 = AnEnumeration.aSimpleCase
let b2 = AnEnumeration.anotherSimpleCase
a2 == b2 // Should be false.

let a3 = AnEnumeration.aMoreComplexCase("Hello")
let b3 = AnEnumeration.aMoreComplexCase("Hello")
a3 == b3 // Should be true.

let a4 = AnEnumeration.aMoreComplexCase("Hello")
let b4 = AnEnumeration.aMoreComplexCase("World")
a3 == b3 // Should be false.
```

Sadly, these all produce this errors like this one:

```
error: MyPlayground.playground:7:4: error: binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'AnEnumeration' operands
a1 == b1 // Should be true.
~~ ^  ~~

MyPlayground.playground:7:4: note: binary operator '==' cannot be synthesized for enums with associated values
a1 == b1 // Should be true.
~~ ^  ~~
```

Translation: If your enumeration uses associated values, you can't test it for equivalency.

Note: If `.aMoreComplexCase` (and the corresponding tests) were removed, then the code would work as expected.

It looks like in the past people have decided to use operator overloading to get around this: [How to test equality of Swift enums with associated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339807/how-to-test-equality-of-swift-enums-with-associated-values). But now that we have Swift 4, I wonder if there is a better way? Or if there have been changes that make the linked solution invalid?

Thanks!

Comment: Those answers are still valid. It will become simpler when https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md is implemented.

Comment: That's what I needed. I've got my code now working properly. Perhaps you should make this comment be an answer, so I can mark this as resolved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Swift proposal

- [SE-0185 Synthesizing Equatable and Hashable conformance](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md)

has been accepted and implemented in **Swift 4.1** (Xcode 9.3):

> ... synthesize conformance to Equatable/Hashable if all of its members are Equatable/Hashable.

therefore it suffices to

> ... opt-in to automatic synthesis by declaring their type as Equatable or Hashable without implementing any of their requirements.

In your example – since `String` is `Equatable` – it will suffice to declare

```
enum AnEnumeration: Equatable {
  case aSimpleCase
  case anotherSimpleCase
  case aMoreComplexCase(String)
}
```

and the compiler will synthesize a suitable `==` operator.

Comment: Any idea why this would be *opt-in*, not opt-out?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth: It is explained at https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md#requesting-synthesis-is-opt-in .